# Cannot save gray frames, but no problems to save the original color frames

Tags: python, opencv

Installed python 2.7 and opoencv 3.1. Try to run a sample code found online. I can use imshow to view each frame in gray, but the output gray level video cannot be opened or played by VLC.

When I replace out.write(gray_image) with out.write(frame) to save the original color frame, the output video is a good copy of the input video. I don't understand why the gray level frames cannot be saved properly.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("small.mp4")
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0,(560,320))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # shape of frame: (320L,560L,3L)
    if ret==True:
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        out.write(gray_image)
        # shape of gray_image: (320L, 560L)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set `isColor` argument to `False`

VideoWriter constructors
Python: cv2.VideoWriter([filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize[, **isColor**]])

BTW, in my practice with MS Windows sometimes gray video could not be created properly without `ffmpeg` libraries available.